# msdeploy" -verb:delete -dest:apphostconfig="Test"

Tags: iis, msdeploy

When using

`"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy" -verb:delete -dest:apphostconfig="Test"`

I am getting Error: Provider rootWebConfig32 is blocked, by BlockHarmfulDeleteOperations error.

Do you have any idea how I can fix that?

thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the apphostconfig provider internally references/invokes the **rootWebConfig** and **machineConfig** providers.

However, these providers will be blocked because of the rule **"BlockHarmfulDeleteOperations"**.

You can exclude the root web.config and the machine.config file. Try

```
msdeploy –verb:delete –dest:apphostconfig="Test" –skip:objectname=machineconfig –skip:objectname=rootwebconfig
```